# Why the regex to match a project tag is not working?

Tags: python

Can anyone provide guidance on why the following regex is not working?

```
project = 'AirPortFamily'
line = 'AirPortFamily-1425.9:'
if re.findall('%s-(\d+):'%project,line):
    print line
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
AirPortFamily-1425.9
```

Comment: Are there only digits after - and before :?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen and @Loocid yes,there are only digits after - and before but the digits can be of the format`1425`,`1425.9`,`1425.9.111`,`1425.1.1.1`

Comment: I mean, a dot isn’t a digit. Digit is not the same as a number that a human can understand. It’s a digit. So you’ll have to also accept the dot in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should match the optional groups of digits preceded by a dot:

```
if re.findall(r'(%s-\d+(?:\.\d+)*):'%project,line):
```

Comment: How do we not capture the `:` at the end?

Comment: Indeed I did not notice the `:` that the OP included in this original regex and left it there. I've removed it now. Thanks.

Comment: Yep that was only part had me stumped so explain to me how the asterisk works if you don't mind

Comment: I mean I could google it but :) I just threw you and alley oop <3

Comment: The asterisk means to match zero or more of the preceding character or group, so in this case there can be optionally a number of groups of a dot followed by a string of digits.

Comment: Okay and OP also mentioned this possibilities `AirPortFamily-1425.9.1.1.1`  with your regex I'm capturing `:` on these variations

Comment: Don't think the `:` is part of the expected output, so it shouldn't be included in the regex.

Comment: I know I'm running your regex with the `1.1.1.1` variants and capturing the `:`

Comment: but if the line contains `line = 'AirPortFamily-1425.9` ,it should not match it...it should only match the lines that contain `:`

Comment: @Flair Sure. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Brandon looks good.

But in case there is a condition like "For a tag to be valid, it must end with a colon(:)"
In order to cover that condition, modifying Brandon's answer a little

```
project = 'AirPortFamily'
line = 'AirPortFamily-1425.9:'
matches = re.findall('%s-\d+\.+\d+\.*\d+:$'%project,line)
if matches:
    for elem in matches:
        print elem.split(':')[0]
```

Here is its working

```
#Matching lines with colon(:) at the end
>>> import re
>>> project = 'AirPortFamily'
>>> line = 'AirPortFamily-1425.9:'
>>> matches = re.findall('%s-\d+\.+\d+\.*\d+:$'%project,line)
>>> if matches:
...     for elem in matches:
...             print elem.split(':')[0]
...
AirPortFamily-1425.9 #Look, the output is the way you want.

#Below snippet with same regex and different line content (without :) doesn't match it
>>> line = 'AirPortFamily-1425.9'
>>> matches = re.findall('%s-\d+\.+\d+\.*\d+:$'%project,line)
>>> if matches:
...     for elem in matches:
...             print elem.split(':')[0]
...
>>> #Here, no output means no match
```

Comment: but if the line contains `line = 'AirPortFamily-1425.9` ,it should not match it...it should only match the lines that contain `:`

Comment: Exactly. The regex that I suggested matches only the tags with colon (:) in the end ($)

Comment: Oh, I got your requirement now.
You want to match tags that ends with colon and as output, you want it to be printed without colon.

I have modified my answer

Comment: Please accpet an answer if any of them worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is missing the . after the first set of numbers. Here's a working example:

```
project = 'AirPortFamily'
line = 'AirPortFamily-1425.9:'
matches = re.findall('%s-\d+\.\d+'%project,line)
if matches:
    print matches
```

Comment: but if the line contains `line = 'AirPortFamily-1425.9` ,it should not match it...it should only match the lines that contain `:`

Answer (score 0):

This is my regex,[my test on regex101 edit again](https://regex101.com/r/nVvpBd/2/)

```
import re
project = 'AirPortFamily'
line = 'AirPortFamily-1425.9:AirPortfamily-14.5.9AirPortFamily-14.2.5.9:'
result = re.findall('%s[0-9.-]+:'%project,line) #this dose not cantain ':' [s[:-1] for s in re.findall('%s[0-9.-]+:'%project,line)]
if result:
    for each in result:
        print (each)
```

Comment: but if the line contains `line = 'AirPortFamily-1425.9` ,it should not match it...it should only match the lines that contain `:`

Comment: it means only match begain with `AirPortFamily-` before `:`,the result of `AirPortFamily-1425.9:AirPortfamily-14.5.9AirPortFamily-14.2.5.9:` is `AirPortFamily-1425.9:` and `AirPortFamily-14.2.5.9:`?

Answer (score 0):

On the possibilities with `1.1.1.1.1` I'm getting the `:` so just stripping it from the results

```
if re.findall(r'%s-[\d+\.\d+]+:'%project,line):
    print(line.strip(':'))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 formats.py 
> AirPortFamily-1425.9.1.1.1
> ```

Comment: but if the line contains `line = 'AirPortFamily-1425.9` ,it should not match it...it should only match the lines that contain `:`

Comment: fixed that just added the `:` to the the `regex` again though your output doesn't desire the `:` to be included so we can `strip` it after we find it

Comment: but this isnt matching something like `AirPortFamily-1425.16:`